OAuth2Error "Code not valid" in login authentication using Spring Security and Keycloak
The login authentication of my website is implemented using Spring Security and Keycloak and authorization_code is used as authorization grant type. I want to study the authentication flow implemented by Spring Security using debug mode.
However, as long as debug mode is used and trace codes step-by-step, there will be OAuth2AuthorizationException due to OAuth2Error with description "Code not valid" and errorCode "invalid_grant" in getResponse(authorizationCodeAuthentication). Relevant codes are shown below.
public class OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    ......
    OAuth2AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = getResponse(authorizationCodeAuthentication);
        ......
        return authenticationResult;
    }
    
    private OAuth2AccessTokenResponse getResponse(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken authorizationCodeAuthentication) {
        try {
            return this.accessTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest(authorizationCodeAuthentication.getClientRegistration(), authorizationCodeAuthentication.getAuthorizationExchange()));
        } catch (OAuth2AuthorizationException ex) {
            ......
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(oauth2Error, oauth2Error.toString(), ex);
        }
    }
}

modified log messages in console:
12:33:28.317 [nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG        org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP POST https://example.com/auth/realms/{realm name}/protocol/openid-connect/token
12:33:28.318 [nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG        org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
12:33:28.321 [nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG        org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [{grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[fd342c34-7c5b-4d71-a19c-5e5882b7666d.d3d0f268-9e26-4f08-8862-975b44eed7fb.77c8ed41-8300-46aa-b2d3-8984821c45e3], redirect_uri=[redirect_uri]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
12:33:37.021 [nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG        org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
However, if all break points are released immediately once entering the debug mode, there will be no OAuth2AuthorizationException and log messages are shown below.
17:46:04.554 [nio-8090-exec-3] DEBUG        org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP POST https://example.com/auth/realms/{realm name}/protocol/openid-connect/token
17:46:05.688 [nio-8090-exec-3] DEBUG        org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
17:46:05.719 [nio-8090-exec-3] DEBUG        org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [{grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[f8c7294f-17d8-48b5-bf31-36cd837e78a2.4c97cd28-2712-4dcd-94fd-2932853674de.77c8ed41-8300-46aa-b2d3-8984821c45e3], redirect_uri=[redirect_uri]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
17:46:26.847 [nio-8090-exec-3] DEBUG        org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 200 OK
17:46:29.081 [nio-8090-exec-3] DEBUG        org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading to [org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse] as "application/json"
I can't figure out what the problem is. Could someone please help?

How long are you letting this "idle" in the debugger? There is usually a time limit on how long the code can be exchanged for a token; often a minute, maybe even less.

If I spend more than 1 minute on the debugger, there will be OAuth2AuthorizationException. However, if all break points are released immediately (less than 30 seconds) after entering the debug mode, there will be no  such exception and login authentication is successful. @CBore
